# Select elements jQuery with Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML page where many elements are dynamically inserted as the user requests. Each of these elements have an id attribute with some string plus a numeric id value plus another string.

Example: `budget_budget_alive_elements_attributes_10_unit_value`

And so I tried the following selector:

```
$("#budget_budget_alive_elements_attributes_\d+_unit_value");
```

But it unfortunately does not work.

Some person [wrote an article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) of an extension to jQuery selector for fetching these kinds of ids but I had no luck with that, either.

Can you help me here? Given the constraints of the element's id values, how can I make a selector for them?

Comment: You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: I think `$('[id^="budget_budget_alive_elements_attributes_"][id$="_unit_value"]');` is good enough, if you still want to validate the digits then use a regex and `.filter()`

Comment: thanks @ArunPJohny. Your answer is precisely that!

Answer (score 3):

You'd better use class selector (by adding same class to these elements).

Else you have to use something like:

```
$("[id^='idbudget_budget_alive_elements_attributes']")
```

Comment: I agree, if you've got groups of elements that do the same thing, classes are the way to go.